# Keybinding to open a specific file in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I presume this is achievable through editing `keybindings.json`. As I can't seem to find a list of available commands, I've got this far through auto-complete:

```
    {
        "key": "SHORTCUT",
        "command": "workbench.action.files.openFile",
        "args": {
         // ARG TO POINT TO SPECIFIC FILE
        }
    }
```

Seems a simple task but I can't seem to find the documentation I'm after. If someone could also point me to the relevant docs I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also looking for this and reading the source code

`vscode/src/vs/workbench/browser/actions/workspaceActions.ts`

It does not use arguments and straight calls a dialog service to show the FileOpen dialog of the OS.

I have made an **Open File** command in the extension [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links#open-a-file) possible to be called from a keybinding.

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i ctrl+o",  // or any other key binding
    "command": "htmlRelatedLinks.openFile",
    "args": [ "/home/mememe/Projects/Python/README.md", 10, 5 ]
  }
```

Comment: The ability to go to a line number is great.  Have a look at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.openfile for relative paths too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it using a vscode shortcut:

- Open keybindings from the command palette `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`
- Add the following JSON:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+m",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
      "text": "code ~/.vscode/notes.txt\u000D"
    }
  }
```

- Replace the above json with the file you'd like to open and your desired shortcut
- Profit

Answer (score 0):

And here's perhaps the simplest and fastest way to do it (via an extension):

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tgreen7.open-file-command