# Vscode open a file without dialog

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to quickly open a specific file (Console.R as a example) by a keyboard without the appearance of a dialog (like `Ctrl + o` or `Ctrl + p`, which pop up a dialog to select which file)?

I have a specific file and just want to open it quickly. For R language terminal is lack of many useful characteristics (like auto-completion and syntax highlighting), I want to allocate a specific file (like Console.R) as the input of R terminal but I don't find a way to open a specific file quickly.

Sorry, this is duplicated with [Keybinding to open a specific file in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57080345/keybinding-to-open-a-specific-file-in-vscode/65153368#65153368) and [vscode keyboard shortcuts to specific files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59662135/vscode-keyboard-shortcuts-to-specific-files?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: the extension [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links#open-a-file) has a command that can be used in a keybinding to open  a file, or maybe [File Group](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.FileGroup) is an option

Comment: Thanks for telling me that. I'm learning how to use [vscode-powertools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=egomobile.vscode-powertools), but I failed to create a command to open a file for my poor `js` basis. I'll try these both extensions, Thanks for your help!

Comment: `HTML Related Links` works well, Thanks for your help!

Comment: [QuickFiles](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kleinsch.quickfiles) is another extension providing such functions.